Lie derivative with non-stationary velocity $u$
I am currently looking at a MHD system on $\Omega_T = \Omega\times (0, T]$
$$
\begin{align}
    \label{eqn:velocity-MF}\mathbf{u} &= \tau \mathbf{j}\times\mathbf{B}, \\
    \mathbf{E}+ \mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{B} &= \mathbf{0}, \\
    \mathbf{j}& = \nabla\times \mathbf{B}, \\
    \label{eqn:magnetic-advection}\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t} &= -\nabla\times \mathbf{E}, \\
    \nabla\cdot \mathbf{B}& = 0
\end{align}
$$
with initial condition $B_0$ and boundary conditions
$$
 \mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{n} = 0, \quad \mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{n} = 0, \quad \mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{0}, \quad \mathbf{J}\times\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{0} \quad \text{on } \Gamma_T
$$
and I formulated it abstractly by using Lie derivative (I view $B$ as a 2-form. )
$$
\partial_t B + L_u B = 0
$$
where $u = \tau (j\wedge B)$ and $j=\nabla\times B$ and $\tau$ is a parameter. For this abstract equation, I would like to study its well-posedness, the energy estimate tells me
$$
\epsilon(t) + \int_0^t||\mathbf{u}(\cdot, s)||^2 ds \leq \epsilon(0)
$$
where $\epsilon(t) = \frac{1}{2}||B(\cdot, t)||^2$ is the magnetic energy. Therefore, the system is dissipative. Moreover, it can be shown that this equation is (degenerate) parabolic.
However, since the velocity is a high-order expression instead of a given one, I cannot use a theorem like Hille-Yosida directly, I am wondering whether there is a nonlinear version of such theorem where I can study the properties of the operator $L_u$. I appreciate any suggestions.

"since the velocity is a high-order expression instead of a given one" ???? What does that even mean?
